# How to install chromedriver in the docker file for jmeter

Tags: docker, selenium, jmeter, selenium-chromedriver

I have deployed jmeter in kubernetes by using

https://github.com/kubernauts/jmeter-kubernetes

But I am facing difficulties when I want to integrate selenium webdriver with jmeter. I am able to install selenium packages within the docker using

```
RUN cd /jmeter/apache-jmeter-$JMETER_VERSION/ && wget -q -O /tmp/jpgc-webdriver-3.3.zip https://jmeter-plugins.org/files/packages/jpgc-webdriver-3.3.zip && unzip -n /tmp/jpgc-webdriver-3.3.zip && rm /tmp/jpgc-webdriver-3.3.zip
```

But how to install chromedriver within docker. There is no official documentation for jmeter on this and  I am new to jmeter. I really appreciate if anyone would guide me on this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no official documentation for JMeter because JMeter doesn't support Selenium

You should look into official documentation for [Chromedriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/) and [Docker](https://www.docker.com/)

Given you were able to come up with [RUN](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run) directive to download and unpack WebDriver Sampler plugin you should be able to do the same with the Chromedriver, like:

```
RUN wget -q -O /tmp/chromedriver.zip https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/87.0.4280.20/chromedriver_linux64.zip && unzip /tmp/chromedriver.zip && rm /tmp/chromedriver.zip && mv chromedriver/tmp
```

You will also need to change the [ENTRYPOINT](https://github.com/kubernauts/jmeter-kubernetes/blob/4659b49f36d64f0bd590d08459299db74936b6e9/openshift/Dockerfile-slave#L6) to set [`webdriver.chrome.driver`](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started) [JMeter system property](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started) like `-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/tmp/chromedriver`

Comment: nope. Still its not working and it prints nothing. Am I missing anything still?